# Operator that mantains unit vector

Tags: matrices, geometry, vector-spaces

Let $\hat u\in\mathbb R^m$ and $\hat v\in\mathbb R^n$ (with $m \neq n$) represent unit vectors in different vector spaces, and let $B$ be a matrix such that:
$$ B\cdot\hat u=\hat v $$
What kind of matrix must $B$ be to respect this? I mean, what kind of matrix must $B$ be to transform *unit* vectors into *unit* vectors in different vector spaces of different dimension?

Thank you very much.

Comment: $B$ must at least have norm 1, but I don't think this is sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The singular values of its [Singular Value Decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) should all be 1.
Also, $n$ must be greater than $m$ unless you are okay with unit vectors mapping to unit vectors *or zero*.

Comment: If I alternatively wanted $\hat v$ to have norm $\leq 1$, would it be correct to assume that the singular values would be $\leq 1$?

Comment: Yes. In fact, the norm of $\hat v$ will be between the minimum and maximum singular values of $B$.